# Ormlite UpdateBuilder.update() always returns 0 (in android)

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using Ormlite in one of my projects and came across a peculiar behavior. Anytime I use UpdateBuilder.update() to update my tables, it always returns 0 instead of the number of rows that got affected. I manually checked the database to see that the rows actually got updated but it is just that the returned row count is always zero.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843255/sqlite-changes-pragma-reports-0-rows-changed-in-certain-delete-statements) post by Ormlite's author [Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray). He seems to have issues only with the delete statements but update is messed up for me (didn't check delete's return value).

Any one knows the reason for this behavior or is it a limitation of the sqlite version used in Android?

Answer (score 0):

> **No**. it is not a limitation with Android SQLite.

AFIK, the table should contain an identity key.

Also, refer to this link question ...

[Cannot retrieve the latest update value from database after running the ORM Lite UpdateBuilder.update() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053093/cannot-retrieve-the-latest-update-value-from-database-after-running-the-orm-lite)

In the question, you can see a code sample. Check your code if you have implemented it correctly. May be you are missing a minor thing.

Comment: For me, the update goes through successfully. (I could see that the data got updated in the db). It is just that the result returned by update function is always zero instead of being the number of records updated. I will keep looking to see if I have bug anywhere though